# Can the words in these bash strings efficiently be inserted into an sqlite table?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sqlite

I have two bash variables `$FNAMES` and `$LNAMES` that I want to insert into a table in `sqlite` and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Here's a mwe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

FNAMES="John Paul George Ringo"
LNAMES="Lennon McCartney Harrison Starr"

sqlite3 people.db "CREATE TABLE people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);"
sqlite3 people.db "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) <MAGIC> ;"
sqlite3 people.db -cmd ".mode column" "SELECT * FROM people;"
```

I would expect the output of this script to be:

```
fname   lname
------  ---------
John    Lennon
Paul    McCartney
George  Harrison
Ringo   Starr
```

I'm assuming there's something I can replace `<MAGIC>` with to obtain my desired result. Is this possible?

Comment: Using only bash? Is zsh an option? I believe zsh has a feature that makes this more magical (less typing). Alternatively, is an explicit loop more readable to future users of the script?

Comment: I'm in a situation where I have `FNAMES` and `LNAMES` defined. I'm open to any solution that starts with the existance of `FNAMES` and `LNAMES` and produces my desired result. An ideal solution would be POSIX-compliant for portability but I'm open to any ideas that would work at the moment.

Comment: No objections. I like writing sh scripts because I'm new to scripting and like to know when I'm using bashisms, but productivity takes priority of course.

Comment: This looks like it'll work really well until someone asks you to enter their son, [Robert Franklin '; DROP TABLE people; -' Jones](https://xkcd.com/327/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line tool does not support [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), so any attempt to do this in a shell script is going to run into problems with un-escaped quotes and the like.   Dealing with quoted and unquoted variables is already a bit of a pain in shell/bash, and that pain only gets worse when you're working with an SQL database which has its own quoting requirements.

Tasks like this should be done in a language that has a SQLite library. Most commonly used languages, both compiled and interpreted, have such libraries.

Here's a few examples of how to do this in perl:

All of these examples require the [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/) and [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-SQLite) library modules to be installed.  If you're running any Linux distro, these will almost certainly be available as packages.  For example, on Debian, run `sudo apt install libdbd-sqlite3-perl` to install them both.   Most other languages will have similar libraries.

BTW, another reason for not using sh or bash (or other shells) is to avoid the pain of dealing with quotes and word-splitting and related problems that exist in shell scripts but not in other languages (they have their own problems and quirks).

#### With two arrays, `@first` and `@last`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbfile= './people.db';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile");

my @first = qw(John Paul George Ringo);
my @last = qw(Lennon McCartney Harrison Starr);

$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT)');

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO people (fname, lname) VALUES (?,?)');

for my $i (0..$#first) {
  $sth->execute($first[$i],$last[$i]);
};
```

The important thing here is that because I've used a prepared statement, I don't have to care about any annoying characters like quotes in any of the names, and I don't have to take any special actions to deal with them.   The prepared statement causes all of that to be handled automagically.

Save this as, e.g., `sql-arrays.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x sql-arrays.pl`.

You can check that it inserted the records correctly from the shell:

```perl
$ sqlite3 people.db -cmd ".mode column" "SELECT * FROM people;"
fname   lname    
------  ---------
John    Lennon   
Paul    McCartney
George  Harrison 
Ringo   Starr
```

You can, of course, write a perl script to run a SELECT statement and output the records in whatever format you like.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

#### With an associative array (aka hash), `%people`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbfile= './people.db';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile");

my %people = (
  'John'   => 'Lennon',
  'Paul'   => 'McCartney',
  'George' => 'Harrison',
  'Ringo'  => 'Starr',
);

$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);");

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO people (fname, lname) VALUES (?,?)');

for my $person (keys %people) {
  $sth->execute($person,$people{$person});
};
```

NOTE: hashes are stored in no particular order, so the records will be inserted into the database in semi-random order.   You could use `sort keys %people` instead of just `keys %people`, but that will insert the records in sorted order (George,John,Paul,Ringo), which is not the same order as provided (John,Paul,George,Ringo).

Most of the time when working with hashes, the order isn't important.  When it is, it's common to use a separate indexed array to store the required order, and loop over that instead of the semi-random hash keys.

e.g. `@order=qw(John Paul George Ringo);` and, later, `for my $person (@order) { ... };` instead of `for my $person (keys %people) { ... }`.

Anyway, you can see that the order of records in the db is different from the first version:

```perl
$ rm -f people.db
$ ./sql-hash.pl
$ sqlite3 people.db -cmd ".mode column" "SELECT * FROM people;"
fname   lname    
------  ---------
John    Lennon   
Ringo   Starr    
George  Harrison 
Paul    McCartney
```

It's also worth noting that this is a pretty contrived example - a hash key needs to be **unique**, and first names are a long way from being that.  While this example does an OK job of showing the basic idea for the sample data, in real world usage the hash key would be a UUID or a non-repeating sequence or some other unique identifier, and the corresponding field in the database would be a PRIMARY KEY.

More importantly, when running a SELECT query, one of the ways the DBI module can return the matching rows is in a hash or hash reference, and you can iterate over the keys to output and/or process the data.

BTW, `bash` also has associative arrays as well as indexed arrays.  As do ksh, zsh, and awk. Most other languages have some form of [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) or [tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) or similar.

#### With an array of strings containing the full names, `@people`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbfile= './people.db';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile");

my @people = ('John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison', 'Ringo Starr');

$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);");

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO people (fname, lname) VALUES (?,?)');

foreach (@people) {
  my ($first,$last) = split;
  $sth->execute($first,$last);
};
```

This version splits each full name into first and last names, and then inserts them into the database.

This form is particularly useful if you want to read the list of names from a text file (one name per line) instead of using a hard-coded array of strings.

None of the above example scripts can cope with people who have middle names or titles like Mr or Dr, or those whose naming conventions aren't the same as most of the English-speaking world.   With sufficient effort, you could force them to change their names to suit your program, but it's probably easier to just change the algorithm (and the database structure) to deal with such real-world annoyances. People can be so inconvenient. Especially pop stars.

Comment: FYI, with one change to the my `$dbh = DB->connect(...)` line, all the examples here can be made to work with **any** SQL database which has a DBD driver - mysql, mariadb, postgresql, oracle, ms sql, etc.

Comment: "_any attempt to do this in a shell script is going to run into problems with un-escaped quotes_" - only if quoting isn't considered.

Comment: The problems exist.  Dealing with them is a PITA.   Even if you deal with them correctly, and most people don't. (a significant percentage of the \*sh questions on this site are related to quoting and word-splitting problems. not a majority, but probably more than any other type of sh question).   And then you get the added pain of dealing with SQL's own quoting requirements.   And, yes, there are good techniques for dealing with that too (like heredocs).   Buy why bother? it's easier and less stressful and more readable to use a language - the right tool - that avoids all those problems.

Comment: @roaima BTW, your `fname="${fnames[i]//\'/\'\'}"` doesn't do what you think it does.  It **does** convert every single-quote to two single-quotes. Which is correct for most (all?) variants of SQL.   **BUT** the `sqlite3` command **never sees those quotes** inside the sql string - they're gobbled up by the shell running sqlite3.   To work, it would need to be `fname="${fnames[i]//\'/\'\\\'\\\'\'}"` or something like that (and that's possibly/probably wrong too because it's unreadable garbage worthy of many expletives ending in "screw that, i'll use perl or python").

Comment: `fname="${fnames[i]//\'/}"` would have exactly the same result as `fname="${fnames[i]//\'/\'\'}"` and be slightly easier to read.

Comment: @ cas I go it to work in bash. (except the question has FNAMES is a string not an array in thwe question) - string allowd for easie magic anyway.

Comment: @Jasen there is no doubt that a bash script **can** be written to insert records into an sqlite database (it can, but you can't use prepared statements), the issue is whether it's worth the bother or if it's a "good" way to do it.  IMO it is not - which is why I wrote my answer.   BTW, your script (after fixing the syntax error on line 5 - should be just `argz[0]=`, not `argz[$0]=`) has the same quoting problem as roaima's script - `sqlite3` will never see any dual single-quotes `''` in the SQL string because they'll be gobbled up by the shell - they need to be escaped to be passed to sqlite3.

Comment: changing $0 made no difference at all (i have not tried to figure out why), it still works perfectly. apostrophes work fine...  you should test it before making inccorrect assumptions. prepared statements are not necessarily a win over parsed,  if there are 1000 records to insert a single parsed insert will probably be faster than 1000 calls to a prepared insert.

Comment: @Jasen 1. I tested it. I copied the script from your answer and saved it to `jasen.sh`, made it executable and ran it.  That's how I saw the syntax error on line 5.  Changing $0 worked for me.  Without changing it to 0, it was trying to use the script's name (`jasen.sh`) as an index for `argz[]` - which fails because argz had already been created as an indexed, not associative, array.   2. RE: prepared statements: you are wrong.  even if you were right, correctness is more important than speed.

Comment: FYI: error message was `./jasen.sh: line 5: ./jasen.sh: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "./jasen.sh")`

Comment: I was just ccopying and pasting on the command-line this is probably why I didn't see that error.

Comment: Hi @cas I've installed sqlite3 and tested my code, including the name Andrew O'Brien. Worked perfectly. I don't understand why you had issues with my quote-escaping code...?

Comment: @roaima mostly because i somehow missed seeing the double-quotes around the entire sql insert string.  I tend to think of bash's `${parameter/pattern/replace}` as bash's "hold-my-beer" moment - as if bash had heard of perl being accused of being read-only because of regex operators and declared "hold my beer! I'll do that with f-ing globs!".   It's sometimes useful but has the detrimental effect of encouraging people to do things with bash that bash is just not suited for, and discourages learning more suitable languages, e.g. all the bash while/read crap posted here that should use awk or sed

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `bash` script that will do the `<MAGIC>` you want

```
#!/bin/bash
#
FNAMES="John Paul George Ringo Andrew Nicci"
LNAMES="Lennon McCartney Harrison Starr O'Brien Müller"

# Convert strings to space-separated arrays (lists)
# Bad things will happen if you have names with spaces (e.g. "Sarah" + "Maddison Smith")
fnames=($FNAMES)
lnames=($LNAMES)

# Create table
# echo "sqlite3 people.db 'CREATE TABLE people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);'"
sqlite3 people.db 'CREATE TABLE people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);'

# Loop across data
# Hope that there are the same number of surnames as forenames
for ((i=0; i<${#fnames[@]}; i++))
do
    # Escape quotes (' becomes ''). Other SQL variants may require a different process
    fname="${fnames[i]//\'/\'\'}"
    lname="${lnames[i]//\'/\'\'}"
    
    # Insert the data
    # echo "sqlite3 people.db \"INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) values ('$fname', '$lname');\""
    sqlite3 people.db "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) values ('$fname', '$lname');"
done

# Report on the result
# echo "sqlite3 people.db -cmd '.mode column' 'SELECT * FROM people;'"
sqlite3 people.db -cmd '.mode column' 'SELECT * FROM people;'
```

I've tested - with two extra names in the dataset for potential edge issues - and it works as expected:

```
John        Lennon
Paul        McCartney
George      Harrison
Ringo       Starr
Andrew      O'Brien
Nicci       Müller
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash function called MAGIC that takes n space separated lists and converts them into a set of SQL values,  thus retaining most of your original syntax.  it uses standard SQL escaping  which so far as I can tell is the syntax expected by Sqlite.

It will work for any number of columns greater than zero.

```
# MAGIC  a variadic function. 
# named for a comment in the question.
# takes one or more space-delimited lists and turns them
# into an SQL VALUES clause with SQL99 standard quoting.
# returns true, presents the result on stdout.
MAGIC(){
   local sep1 sep2 argz i
   argz=( "$@" )
   argz[0]="${argz[0]} " # ensure termination
   sep1="VALUES " 
   while [ "${argz[0]}" != "" ]
   do
      sep2=""
      echo -n "$sep1("
      for(( i=0; i<$# ; ++i ))
      do
         v=${argz[$i]%% *}
         echo -n "$sep2'${v//\'/\'\'}'"
         argz[$i]="${argz[i]#* }"
         sep2=','
      done
      echo -n ")"
      sep1=','
   done
}

FNAMES="John Paul George Ringo"
LNAMES="Lennon McCartney Harrison Starr"
    
sqlite3 people.db "CREATE TABLE people(fname TEXT, lname TEXT);"
sqlite3 people.db "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) $(MAGIC "$FNAMES" "$LNAMES" ) ;"
sqlite3 people.db -cmd ".mode column" "SELECT * FROM people;"
```

Comment: cas pointed out that I has [$0] where I meant [0] but mysteriouly that didn't cause any problem when I pasted it on the command line.

Comment: @Cas  What do you mean correcness?  apostrpohes work fine with this code.

Comment: You're going to the trouble of converting single apostrophes to double apostrophes.  That's the correct way to insert an apostrophe into a column for most, if not all, variants of SQL.   The trouble is that the sqlite3 command never actually sees the double apostrophes.  They're gobbled up by the shell.  so, e.g. if you add an apostrophe into John, `'Joh''n'` becomes just `'John'`.  To work, the apostrophes would need to be escaped, e.g. `'Joh'\'\''n'`.     Try `echo -n "$sep2'${v//\'/\'\\\'\\\'\'}'"` on line 14.

Comment: and that kind of quoting and escaping BS is a small part of the reason why IMO this should not be done in shell.   There are **much** better languages for the job, that don't require dealing with such garbage....and they also have libraries which support prepared statements.   shell is for running and orchestrating programs that do useful work, not for trying to do useful work itself.

Comment: Commentss on my code WHICH WORKS PERFECTLY (now)  belong under my code,  BUT PLEASE TEST IT FIRST.

Comment: 1. I tested it.  2. I explained why it does not do what you think it does.  i.e. apostrophes do not work correctly with your code.  If you can't understand what I wrote, that's a problem you'll need to work on on your own.

Comment: `echo -n "$sep2'${v//\'/\'\'}'"` gives `'joh''n'`  which is perfect and does go to sqlite3 it is not gobbled by the shell becase I use enough double quotes to prevent that.

Comment: the bit that says `$(MAGIC ` is enclosed in double quotes  you need to scroll right to see it clearly.

Comment: Adding backslashes to make stuff work in bash is almost always the wrong approach. What test did you do that didn't work? was it a test of my code?

Comment: It's still a huge mistake to use shell for a task like this.  And an even bigger mistake to not use prepared statements - that's how you leave yourself wide open for SQL injection attacks.  Your function uses 15 lines just to deal with apostrophes alone.  There's a lot more to sanitising sql input than just apostrophes.  Also, the function is useless if any of the fields are numeric because it single-quotes them whether they're strings or not.   Prepared statements work automatically with any kind of data, no need to kludge up some bare-minimum hack.

Comment: My point remains: While you **can** use shell to insert records into an sqlite database, you really **shouldn't**.

Comment: 13 lines are converting one or more space delimited lists into a single inteleaved SQL list one line deals with apostrophes.

Comment: you could do the same with one line of perl. and not have to worry about apostrophes or other annoyances by using prepared statements.

Comment: I cant see that being readable in less than 10 lines. if you include the added overhead.

Comment: It does not surprise me at all that you can't see it.   However:`for my $i (0..$#first) { $joined[$i] = "('$first[$i]', '$last[$i]')" };`.   And that's not even the most succinct or shortest way of doing it.   It would **still** be just as wrong to do it that way in perl or in any other language, because using a prepared statement is the right way to do it.

Comment: oh just the transpose bit,. not the splitting into words or the query part.

Comment: splitting strings by space(s), or anything else, is trivial in perl.  `@first=split $first; @last=split $last;`.    it's trivial in most languages that aren't shell.   The extraordinarily difficult "query part" is also trivial - it's just concatenating a string.   `print 'INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) VALUES (' . join(', ',@joined) . ")";`.   perl has a join function so there's no need to screw around with your stuff like your $sep1 and $sep2 (btw, you would have been better off writing a join function for sh to do that.  It's only 1 or 2 lines)

Comment: hmm, escape all the strings, then split them and then join them I can't see it being significantly easier and it seems kind of dirty relying on the separator passing the escaping process unaltered.  yes it's 20 lines of code or (15 by your generous count) but it's easy to use. the call is inline with the insert statement.